# ObjC: Calling methods from a different class file

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Hi Community,

I'm working on a project where I need to deal with arrays full of hundreds of hundreds of items, so rather than put them all in the delegate class and messing up my code, I've put them in a new class I'm calling "ValueHolder" so that when I call methods of ValueHolder, they will return parts of the large arrays that I need to deal with.

However, I can't figure out for the life of me how to call its methods. I've tried

```
ValueHolder *theValues = [[ValueHolder alloc] init];
```

but it errors out, telling me `ValueHolder undeclared` and `theValues undeclared` Does anyone know how I can deal with this? Thanks,

~Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `.h` of `ValueHolder` in the source of the other class;

```
#import "ValueHolder.h"

// Wherever it was in first place
ValueHolder *theValues = [[ValueHolder alloc] init];
```

Note that if this data is instance specific, you need to acquire the data through the same instance, and not a new instance.

Comment: I knew I was missing something little. Thank you so much!!